# Accessing the data from Json in React Native

Tags: json, react-native, loops

I am trying to access the data from Nested JSON, but it is showing partial data. JSON Extract and access code  are provided below:

**JSON**

```
let tableData = [
  { "id":"1",
    "title":"Joe's Gelato", 
    'tagline':"Desert, Ice cream, £££", 
    'eta':"10-30",
    'imgUri':require('./assets/nasi-briyani-mutton.jpg'),
      'items':[ 
                {"title":"Gelato", 
                  "contents":[{
                                "title":"Vanilla" ,
                                "title":"Chocolate",
                                "title":"Mint"  
                              }]},
                {"title":"Coffee", 
                "contents":[{
                              "title":"Flat white" ,
                              "title":"Latte",
                              "title":"Caffe Americano"  
                            }]}  
                ]
  },

  { 
    "id":"2",
    "title":"Joe's Dinner", 
    'tagline':"Pizza, burgers, £££", 
    'eta':"50+",
    'imgUri':require('./assets/pizza-restaurant.jpg'),
      'items':[{ 
                "title":"Pizza", 
                  "contents":[{
                                "title":"Roco Pizza" ,
                                "title":"Veggi",
                                "title":"Chicken Supreme"  
                              }]},
                {"title":"Burger", 
                "contents":[{
                              "title":"Cubby Burger" ,
                              "title":"Rock Burger",
                              "title":"Chicken Lover"  
                            }]  
                }]
  },
];
```

**React Code**

```
  <ScrollView>
      <TableView>         
            <Text>---Menu---</Text>
            {/* {tableData.map((restaurants,i) => ( */}
              {tableData[0].items.map ((menuSection,i) => (
                <Section header = {menuSection.title}>
                {menuSection.contents.map((dishes,j) => ( 
                      <Cell title = {dishes.title}/> 
                ))}
              </Section>
            ))}
     
       
      </TableView>
    </ScrollView>
```

I am trying to access the last item (contents.title) in nested JSON, but somehow it only shows a partial result instead of the complete list of items. Screen Shot of result is provided below.

[image]

It is showing me the last items in the menu instead of showing complete title list as:

**- Gelato**

```
 Vanilla

 Chocolate

 Mint
```

**- Coffe**

```
 Flat White

 Latte

 Caffe Americano
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **contents** data should be an array then it can map correctly. Currently, it's inside an object, so when you map **contents** array it has only one object inside. Also, title key inside an object will replace the title with the last value.

**Solution - Alter data remove the object and then map.**

```
 contents: ['Roco Pizza', 'Veggi', 'Chicken Supreme']

{menuSection.contents.map((dishes, j) => (
          <Cell title={dishes} />
        ))}
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my problem. You are right, there is no need to have title provided multiple time for the same item.

Comment: Thats great, if the answer help you out you can upvote and mark the answer as right. Thanks!